# dynamic JSF composite component styling/rendering

Tags: jsf, rendering, stylesheet, composite, composite-component

I've a little problem with a composite component. This component's implementation looks like:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="foo.css" library="bar"/>

    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <composite:insertChildren/>
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

It is included dynamically into a facelet page which include this component with JSTL core tags. The facelet page is similar to the following one.

```
<h:panelGroup id="viewport" layout="block">
    <c:if test="#{controller.object != null}">
        <c:forEach items="#{controller.object.elements}" var="element">
            <c:if test="#{element.type == 'type1'}">
                <my:componentTypeOne id="#{element.id}"/>
            </c:if>

            <c:if test="#{element.type == 'type2'}">
                <my:componentTypeTwo id="#{element.id}"/>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</h:panelGroup>
```

So when I only render the `viewport` of the page the components are rendered but without the stylesheet defined within the composite component `my:component`. Is there any way to include the stylesheet on the fly without rendering the whole page?

**EDIT:** extension of the example code..

Comment: Do you really need to use JSTL? You could change `<c:forEach>` for `<ui:repeat>`, and `<c:if>` for the `rendered` attribute. JSTL doesn't run in sync with JSF, although I can't tell if that's the problem.

Comment: No I don't think so. It should be possible to replace the `<c:forEach>` but I need an equivalent for the `<c:if>` tag because there should be more component types in future

Comment: That's not a problem, just wrap all of the components inside a <h:panelGroup> and set its rendered attribute.

Comment: I will try this way tommorrow. Thanks so far for your suggestion!

Comment: @RinaldoPJr: replacing `<c:forEach>` by `<ui:repeat>` would only result in duplicate component ID errors. Not really what the OP wanted.

Comment: @BalusC The ID is not static, why would that happen? And, as I said, I don't know if that would solve his problem, it was only a suggestion. :)

Comment: @RinaldoPJr: you end up with multiple components with the same ID in the component tree, which are only conditionally rendered. Multiple components with the same ID in one tree is invalid. JSTL runs during view build time, not during view render time and that's why this approach works only with JSTL. You end up with only one component in the tree instead of multiple which is conditionally rendered when using `<ui:repeat>` and `rendered` instead of `<c:forEach>` and `<c:if>`. Read this answer carefully and try it out yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984

Comment: @BalusC Yes, I understood what you said. I just hadn't seen that he edited the question and added another component with the same ID. It wasn't there. :P Although I don't think I'd have spotted it anyway.

Comment: If there exists another way to add composite components of various types dynamically to the page this would be helpful too!